What would the unit for the slope of a graph where the $x$-axis is mass and the $y$-axis is the drag coefficient?
I have written a paper on the effect of change in mass on the drag coefficient of a ping pong ball. While making my last calculations, I decided to use the slope of the final graph (where the $x$ axis is the mass condition and the $y$ axis is the drag coefficient) to do error calculations. When I turned my paper in, my teacher asked for me to declare the unit for the slopes' of the maximum and minimum worst lines of best fit.
My problem is that I don't really know what the unit would be as drag coefficient is dimensionless. I have thought about using an arbitrary unit, but any help would be appreciated.

I don't think there is any unit of drag coefficient.

So is it fine if I use an arbitrary unit for the slope of the graph?

I think instead of using an arbitrary unit, $\text{kg}^{-1}$ or $\text{g}^{-1}$ would be more preferable

Thanks a lot for your help. Do you think kg^-1 fine or should I go for Cd kg^-1?

I think $\text{kg}^{-1}$ would be fine.

Drag coefficient is a function of shape.  It's not a function of mass.

I know that it is a function of shape, the paper's conclusion is that the model is faulty in assuming that the drag coefficient is dependent on mass . Thanks for pointing it out anyways.

By definition, the slope of a graph is the ratio between the vertical variation (drag coefficient) and the horizontal variation (mass). If you want the unit for the slope, it will therefore be $\text{kg}^{-1}$ if mass is measured in kilograms.
